# Firefox Saving Booksmarks to the incorrect folder

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

A few weeks ago, I noticed that whenever I save a bookmark in Firefox, it goes to the `Other Bookmarks` folder not the the main bookmark menu.

Is it possible to set a default location for newly saved bookmarks, so that I can set it to save in the main bookmarks menu? Is this a bug in some version of Firefox that Mozilla isn't aware of?

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but this exact same question (and answer) were posted less than two weeks ago. In the future, please take a few minutes to search through our previous questions before posting a new one. There is a fairly good chance that someone else has encountered the same problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Run5k lol. Didn't know about the dupe. My answer is almost identical to yours! ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill I noticed!  ;-)  No worries, my friend.  It happens to the best of us, and it was all done in the spirit of helping the OP as much as possible.  That's what really counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is it possible to set a default location for newly saved bookmarks?

This appears to be an issue with Firefox Quantum, as reported by other users:

> Before firefox quantum, when pressing Ctrl+D, the created bookmark was
>   put in the bookmarks menu by default (unlike clicking the star
>   bookmark button, which defaulted to unsorted bookmarks). After
>   updating to quantum, the default location is "Other bookmarks" - the
>   same as pressing the star button.
>
> How do I restore the old behaviour?

...

> Unsorted Bookmarks was renamed to Other Bookmarks back in the Firefox
>   56 or 55 version, so they are essentially the same thing although some
>   users may see both those folders with different bookmarks in each. I
>   had that happen with one of my Profiles, but not the other one.

Source [Put bookmarks in bookmarks menu by default | Firefox Support Forum | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1195435)

A workaround is to install the [Default Bookmark Folder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/default-bookmark-folder/) add-on:

> Allows you to choose the default bookmark location folder and quickly bookmark pages via a dedicated icon.